# Using canvas pointermove event on phone, the pointerleave event gets fired

Tags: javascript, mobile, html5-canvas, pointer-events

I am just trying to draw on my phone using "pointer" events.

This works on my desktop with my mouse, but not on my (android) phone.
I should be able to draw curved lines, but dragging with my finger on my phone results in an "enter" and a few "moves" but then it "leave"s.

It has to be online:  https://dbarc.net/SOtest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- works on desktop, leaves on phone (dbarc.net/SOtest.html) -->
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
body { width:400px; }
#canvas { background:#eee; }    
    </style>
    <script>
  "use strict";
  let canvas, ctx, xx, yy, infodiv;
window.onload = function() {
  infodiv = document.getElementById("infodiv"); // info output
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//  canvas.addEventListener('pointerenter', function() { ptrEnter(); } );
  canvas.addEventListener('pointerenter', ptrEnter); // better
  canvas.addEventListener('pointerleave', ptrLeave);
  canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', ptrMove);
}
function ptrEnter() { // shows an enter
  infodiv.innerHTML += "ENTER ";
}
function ptrLeave() { // shows a leave
  infodiv.innerHTML += "LEAVE ";
}
function ptrMove(ev) { // draws (no pen up/down)
  infodiv.innerHTML += "m ";
  let x0 = canvas.offsetLeft, y0 = canvas.offsetTop;
  let xold = xx, yold = yy;
  xx = Math.floor(ev.clientX) - x0; 
  yy = Math.floor(ev.clientY) - y0;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(xold,yold);
  ctx.lineTo(xx, yy);
  ctx.stroke(); 
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>  
    <div id="infodiv">Events: </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: (After "several hours")  By putting in the CSS style statement  < br />
 `canvas { touch-action: none; } `, it works.  @gsharew

Comment: I did close your question as a duplicate, you can tag me in your comments using `@Kaiido` since I did interact with it. I stand by my decision.  I'm sorry if the relation between this Q/A and the other one wasn't as obvious to you as it was to me. I should have posted the following comment when closing your question, but lacked time then:

Comment: Your core problem is that your page did scroll and thus the *pointermove* event got overridden by that default scrolling operation. To prevent that from happening, you need to set the `touch-action: none` rule. The answer you gave the bounty to did avoid your problem entirely by not using the *pointermove* event at all, that hardly answers the question you did ask.

Comment: This question is [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422963). @Kaiido

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours I came to the right solution for this problem.
First the event should be ***touchmove*** not **"mousemove"** for the device which are not desktop. Second to get the values for clientX and clientY you have to use ***event.targetTouchs[0].clientX*** or ***.clientY***. The full code is like below.

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- works on desktop, leaves on phone (dbarc.net/SOtest.html) -->

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            width: 400px;
        }

        #canvas {
            background: #eee;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        "use strict";
        let canvas, ctx, xx, yy, infodiv;
        let isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
        window.onload = function () {
            infodiv = document.getElementById("infodiv"); // info output
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.addEventListener('pointerenter', function () { ptrEnter(); });
            canvas.addEventListener('pointerleave', function () { ptrLeave(); });
            canvas.addEventListener(isMobile ? 'touchmove' : "mousemove", function (ev) { ptrMove(ev); });
        }
        function ptrEnter() { // shows an enter
            infodiv.innerHTML += "ENTER ";
        }
        function ptrLeave() { // shows a leave
            infodiv.innerHTML += "LEAVE ";
        }
        function ptrMove(ev) { // draws (no pen up/down)
            infodiv.innerHTML += "m ";
            let x0 = canvas.offsetLeft, y0 = canvas.offsetTop;
            let xold = xx, yold = yy;

            if (isMobile) {
                xx = Math.floor(ev.targetTouches[0].clientX) - x0;
                yy = Math.floor(ev.targetTouches[0].clientY) - y0;
            } else {
                xx = ev.clientX - x0;
                yy = ev.clientY - y0;
            }

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(xold, yold);
            ctx.lineTo(xx, yy);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    <div id="infodiv">Events: </div>
</body>

</html> -->
```

Comment: And `('pointerenter', ptrEnter)` is better than `('pointerenter', function() { ptrEnter(); } )`  Thanks.